# EasyAdmin: Specifying a page in CrudController

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, easyadmin3

How can I give my Crud controller a specific template?

For example, I have the `user` entity linked to its controller `UserCrudController`.

I want the creation page to be another page than the one provided by EasyAdmin by default (`templates/user/new.html.twig`).

How do I specify this in the `CrudController` ?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/design.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overrideTemplate`.
**Example**

```
public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            // ...
            ->overrideTemplate('crud/layout', 'admin/layout.html.twig')
        ;
    }
```